# webpack Unknown word > 1 | import React from "react"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

when I run npm run dev (webpack --mode=development) I got the following error.
I m using webpack with Reactjs .

ERROR in ./src/index.js (./node_modules/imports-loader/dist/cjs.js!./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--4-3!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src!./src/index.js)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
SyntaxError

(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | import React from 'react';
>       | ^
>     2 | import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
>     3 | import './index.css';

package.json

```
{
    "name": "uitest",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "dependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.10.2",
        "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.10.1",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.2",
        "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
        "cra-template": "1.0.3",
        "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-hot-loader": "^4.11.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
        "yarn": "^1.22.4",
        "webpack": "4.43.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "webpackdevserver": "webpack-dev-server",
        "dev": "webpack-dev-server --mode=development",
        "prod": "webpack --mode=production",
        "build": "webpack --config prod.config.js",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
            ">0.2%",
            "not dead",
            "not op_mini all"
        ],
        "development": [
            "last 1 chrome version",
            "last 1 firefox version",
            "last 1 safari version"
        ]
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "css-loader": "^3.6.0",
        "imports-loader": "^1.0.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1"
    }
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path')
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: true,
    },
    entry: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.js'),
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: "main.js"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.m?js$|jsx|css/,
            exclude: /node_modules/,
            use: [
                "babel-loader",
                'style-loader',
                'imports-loader',
                {
                    loader: 'css-loader',
                    options: {
                        importLoaders: 2,
                        // 0 => no loaders (default);
                        // 1 => postcss-loader;
                        // 2 => postcss-loader, sass-loader
                    },
                },
                'postcss-loader',
            ]
        }, ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/index.html'),
            filename: 'index.html'
        })
    ],

};
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';


ReactDOM.render( 
    <App/> ,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Comment: what about 'babel-plugin-import', 'style-loader', 'css-loader'? I mean these are missing in your devDependency.

Comment: webpack libraries/plugins are not dependency(required during run time) they are dev dependency (required at initial stage like building)

Comment: I will install 'babel-plugin-import', 'style-loader' and see if something changes

Comment: when I have added  'babel-plugin-import' in devdependencies and in webpack.config.js  I got the error like that 
(1:1) Unknown word

> 1 | [object Object]

Comment: ok can you try separating js | jsx | ts | tsx and write for CSS separately, in webpack.config